# Qnap and bookstack setup with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, qnap

im having issues getting bookstack setup via docker on my qnap.
Any idea's where i'm going wrong with the docker-compose script?

[image]

nothing connects on port 6875, and the bookstacker is showing a connection refused message.
[image]

The database app shows this:
[image]

Comment: If I wanted to reproduce this on my local system, how would I do it, without retyping the contents of your file?  Can you replace the three image files with plain text, so that other people can run run them, and they can be searched for later?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing connects on port 6875 because it is not opened on the NAS network interface (but in an internal virtual network); to solve, you need to edit your `docker-compose.yaml` like this:

```yaml
version: "2"
services:
  bookstack:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/bookstack
    container_name: bookstack
    network_mode: "bridge" # Add this
    environment:
```